# How to Add Autofit column data for excel using C# .NET

Tags: c#, winforms

```
 private void copyAlltoClipboard()
    {
        sdataGridView.SelectAll();
        DataObject dataObj = sdataGridView.GetClipboardContent();
        if (dataObj != null)
            Clipboard.SetDataObject(dataObj);
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        copyAlltoClipboard();
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlexcel;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
        object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
        xlexcel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        
        xlexcel.Visible = true;
        xlWorkBook = xlexcel.Workbooks.Add(misValue);
        xlWorkSheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range CR = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 1];
        CR.Select();
        xlWorkSheet.PasteSpecial(CR, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, true);
        
    }
```

I am using this piece of code to export my datagridview data to excel but i want to add the autofit or merge the column data for column texts including the header. I dont know how to do that.Any help will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To adjust the column width, you can do the following:

```
Excel.Range xlEntireColumn = null;
Excel.Range xlRange = null;

while (reader.Read()) {
for (int i=0;i<numcols;i++) { 
    xlsheet.ActiveSheet.Cells[row,i+1] = reader.GetValue(i).ToString();

    xlRange = xlSheet.ActiveSheet.Cells[row, i+1];
    xlEntireColumn = xlRange.EntireColumn;
    xlEntireColumn.AutoFit();
}
```

check this also..
https://www.dotnetfunda.com/codes/show/1071/export-to-excel-with-grid-color-in-winforms-using-csharp